# ведения счета js игры через cookie

Tags: javascript, cookie

Как осуществить ведение счета в игре крестики-нолики, написанной на js, через cookie?

Собственно, вот мой код, но ведение счета не осуществляется

```
<title>Крестики-нолики</title>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<meta name="generator" content="MS Notepad">
<style>
body{background-image: url(background.jpg);
background-attachment: fixed;
background-size: 100%;}
h1{text-align:center;
font-family: 'Times New Roman' cursive;}
#result
 {
 width: 200px;
 height: 200px;
 background: yellow;
 }
</style>
 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<h1><b> Крестики-нолики</b></h1>
<br>
</p>
<div align="center"><center>

<table border="0">
<tr>
<td align="center"><img src="bl.gif" name="pole0" onClick="Place(0)" width="100" height="100"></td>
<td align="center"><img src="bl.gif" name="pole1" onClick="Place(1)" width="100" height="100"></td>
<td align="center"><img src="bl.gif" name="pole2" onClick="Place(2)" width="100" height="100"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="center"><img src="bl.gif" name="pole3" onClick="Place(3)" width="100" height="100"></td>
<td align="center"><img src="bl.gif" name="pole4" onClick="Place(4)" width="100" height="100"></td>
<td align="center"><img src="bl.gif" name="pole5" onClick="Place(5)" width="100" height="100"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="center"><img src="bl.gif" name="pole6" onClick="Place(6)" width="100" height="100"></td>
<td align="center"><img src="bl.gif" name="pole7" onClick="Place(7)" width="100" height="100"></td>
<td align="center"><img src="bl.gif" name="pole8" onClick="Place(8)" width="100" height="100"></td>
</tr>
</table>
</center></div>
 <div id="result"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
var c = new Array(9);
for (i=0; i<9; i++) c[i] = 0;
x = new Image(100,100);
x.src = "x.gif";
o = new Image(100,100);
o.src = "o.gif";
e = new Image(100,100);
e.src = "bl.gif";

function Cross(value) {
if (value == 0) document.pole0.src = x.src;
if (value == 1) document.pole1.src = x.src;
if (value == 2) document.pole2.src = x.src;
if (value == 3) document.pole3.src = x.src;
if (value == 4) document.pole4.src = x.src;
if (value == 5) document.pole5.src = x.src;
if (value == 6) document.pole6.src = x.src;
if (value == 7) document.pole7.src = x.src;
if (value == 8) document.pole8.src = x.src;
}

function Zero(value) {
if (value == 0) document.pole0.src = o.src;
if (value == 1) document.pole1.src = o.src;
if (value == 2) document.pole2.src = o.src;
if (value == 3) document.pole3.src = o.src;
if (value == 4) document.pole4.src = o.src;
if (value == 5) document.pole5.src = o.src;
if (value == 6) document.pole6.src = o.src;
if (value == 7) document.pole7.src = o.src;
if (value == 8) document.pole8.src = o.src;
}

function CheckVictory() {
if (c[0] == c[1] && c[1] == c[2] && c[2] > 0) return true;
if (c[3] == c[4] && c[4] == c[5] && c[5] > 0) return true;
if (c[6] == c[7] && c[7] == c[8] && c[8] > 0) return true;
if (c[6] == c[3] && c[3] == c[0] && c[0] > 0) return true;
if (c[7] == c[4] && c[4] == c[1] && c[1] > 0) return true;
if (c[8] == c[5] && c[5] == c[2] && c[2] > 0) return true;
if (c[6] == c[4] && c[4] == c[2] && c[2] > 0) return true;
if (c[0] == c[4] && c[4] == c[8] && c[8] > 0) return true;
}

function Comp() {
for (i=0; i<9; i++) if (c[i] == 0) ph = i;
for (i=0; i<3; i++) {
if (c[0] == c[1] && c[2] == 0 && c[0] == i) ph = 2;
if (c[0] == c[2] && c[1] == 0 && c[0] == i) ph = 1;
if (c[1] == c[2] && c[0] == 0 && c[2] == i) ph = 0;
if (c[3] == c[4] && c[5] == 0 && c[3] == i) ph = 5;
if (c[3] == c[5] && c[4] == 0 && c[3] == i) ph = 4;
if (c[4] == c[5] && c[3] == 0 && c[5] == i) ph = 3;
if (c[6] == c[7] && c[8] == 0 && c[6] == i) ph = 8;
if (c[6] == c[8] && c[7] == 0 && c[6] == i) ph = 7;
if (c[7] == c[8] && c[6] == 0 && c[8] == i) ph = 6;

if (c[6] == c[3] && c[0] == 0 && c[6] == i) ph = 0;
if (c[6] == c[0] && c[3] == 0 && c[6] == i) ph = 3;
if (c[3] == c[0] && c[6] == 0 && c[3] == i) ph = 6;
if (c[7] == c[4] && c[1] == 0 && c[7] == i) ph = 1;
if (c[7] == c[1] && c[4] == 0 && c[7] == i) ph = 4;
if (c[4] == c[1] && c[7] == 0 && c[4] == i) ph = 7;
if (c[8] == c[5] && c[2]




== 0 && c[8] == i) ph = 2;
if (c[8] == c[2] && c[5] == 0 && c[8] == i) ph = 5;
if (c[5] == c[2] && c[8] == 0 && c[5] == i) ph = 8;

if (c[6] == c[4] && c[2] == 0 && c[6] == i) ph = 2;
if (c[6] == c[2] && c[4] == 0 && c[6] == i) ph = 4;
if (c[4] == c[2] && c[6] == 0 && c[4] == i) ph = 6;
if (c[0] == c[4] && c[8] == 0 && c[0] == i) ph = 8;
if (c[0] == c[8] && c[4] == 0 && c[0] == i) ph = 4;
if (c[4] == c[8] && c[0] == 0 && c[4] == i) ph = 0;
}
Zero(ph);
c[ph] = 2;
if (CheckVictory() == true) {
alert("Очень жаль, но Вы проиграли. Попытайтесь еще и у Вас получится!)");
GameOver();
}
}
function setCookie(name, value, options) {
 options = options || {};

 var expires = options.expires;

 if (typeof expires == "number" && expires) {
 var d = new Date();
 d.setTime(d.getTime() + expires * 1000);
 expires = options.expires = d;
 }
 if (expires && expires.toUTCString) {
 options.expires = expires.toUTCString();
 }

 value = encodeURIComponent(value);

 var updatedCookie = name + "=" + value;

 for (var propName in options) {
 updatedCookie += "; " + propName;
 var propValue = options[propName];
 if (propValue !== true) {
 updatedCookie += "=" + propValue;
 }
 }

 document.cookie = updatedCookie;
}
function GameOver() {
for (i=0; i<9; i++) c[i] = 0;
document.pole0.src = e.src;
document.pole1.src = e.src;
document.pole2.src = e.src;
document.pole3.src = e.src;
document.pole4.src = e.src;
document.pole5.src = e.src;
document.pole6.src = e.src;
document.pole7.src = e.src;
document.pole8.src = e.src;
}

function CheckNobody() {
nobody = false;
for (i=0; i<9; i++) if (c[i] == 0) nobody = true;
if (nobody == false) {
alert("Ничья. Вы были дойстойным соперником!");
var inprt = prompt("Введите ваше имя");
var f = document.cookie.split(";");
 var t;
 if(document.cookie.length > 0) t = f.length+1;
 else t = 0; 
 document.cookie = "user"+t+"="+inprt;

 document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = document.cookie;

GameOver();
}
}

function Place(value) {
if (c[value] == 0) {
Cross(value);
c[value] = 1;
if (CheckVictory() == true) {
alert("Вы выиграли! Поздравляем!!!");
GameOver();
}
else {
CheckNobody();
Comp();
CheckNobody();
}
}
}
```

Я еще не очень знаю js, поэтому и не могу разобраться

Comment: Вас интересует, как читать и записывать cookie на js?

Comment: почему куки? Аякс, а лучше сокеты

Comment: Для работы с куками в js есть отличный плагин для jQuery - http://plugins.jquery.com/cookie/. Разобраться не составит труда.

Comment: покажите пожалуйста пример, чтобы не уходить с сайта `ru.stackoverflow.com` и не разбираться